# Open a context menu in a matplotlib figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, contextmenu

I would like to open a a context menu in a matplotlib figure, at the time and position that I click the right mouse button in the figure. I want to open it in the coordinates where I press the button, and get those coordinates.

This is my code so far:

```
classs Figure(QMainWindow):

  x1 = 0      #I made this variables to get the coordinates and use it in 
  x2 = 0      # another methods too

  def __init__(self):
    #A lot of stuff in here to create the figure


  def right_click_press(self, event):

    if event.button == 3:       #"3" is the right button

        print "you click the right button" 
        print 'button=%d, x=%d, y=%d, xdata=%f, ydata=%f'%(
        event.button, event.x, event.y, event.xdata, event.ydata)

        #Get the coordinates of the mouse click
        Figure.x1 = event.xdata
        Figure.y1 = event.ydata 

        #I create the action
        noteAction_2 = QAction(QIcon(""), "Insert note",self, 
                                       triggered = self.openDialog)

        #I create the context menu
        self.popMenu = QMenu(self)
        self.popMenu.addAction(noteAction_2)

        cursor = QCursor()
        print cursor.pos()
        #self.connect(self.figure_canvas, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.context_menu)
        #self.popMenu.exec_(self.mapToGlobal(event.globalPos()))

        self.popMenu.exec_() 

  def context_menu(self):
    pass
```

I tried  `globalPos` , `mapToGlobal`, `pos` and trying to make another method (as you can see above) to get to open it where I make the click, but I do not get the result that I want. This is what I get:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already solved it replacing the line:

`self.popMenu.exec_()`

with this:

```
    #I create the context menu
    self.popMenu = QMenu(self)
    self.popMenu.addAction(noteAction_2)

    cursor = QCursor()
    self.popMenu.popup(cursor.pos())
```

By doing this, i discard using another method and i get the coordinates easily.
Hope this help you.